# SUMIFS within a date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on a excel file for my monthly budget. I am exporting my monthly transactions into a CSV file and then copying it over.

I have a tab for each month and all my categorizes that I am budgeting for. I then copy over the csv file to a tab called transactions in my budget workbook. Then I have a drop down list with all the categorizes from my monthly categories. Once I have categorized all my transactions that will total up on the corresponding budget sheet.

The issue I am having a hard time with is how do I create a specific equation that will recognize the month and then the specific category item. For an example "His - Income" I can easily use a sumif to get that information from a list, but how do I now separate further it for April only.

The data is organized on a tab by Date in column "A", description in column "B", and amount in "D". I am looking for an equation that will find "His - income" for 4/1/2015 to 4/30/2015.

Comment: Please, oh please, structure your question to make it easier to read. I got lost half through this text... :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a SUMIFS

`SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2,criteria2])`

With one IF for the category, and two more for the date range. I will look something like this:

```
=SUMIFS(D1:D50, B1:50,"=His - income",A1:A50,">=4/1/2015",A1:A50,"<=4/1/2015")
```

I would change all the hard coded ranges (e.g. D1:D50 to named ranges) as well as the dates. If you put the dates in a cell it will change the formula to something like this: `BudgetDates,"<="&F$1` (notice the ampersand)

Answer (score 0):

The [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) can use operators other than equals; equals is just the default. With *01-Apr-2015* in J1 (sometimes *04/01/2015* formatted a *mmmm*) and *His - Income* in K1, you could use one of the following.

```
=sumifs(D:D, B:B, K1, A:A, ">="&J1, A:A, "<"&edate(J1, 1))
=sumifs(D:D, B:B, K1, A:A, ">="&date(2015, 4, 1), A:A, "<"&date(2015, 5, 1))
=sumifs(D:D, B:B, "His - Income", A:A, ">=4/1/2015", A:A, "<5/1/2015")
```

Unless you want to use it as a visual reminder, the = for exact martch is unnecessary. Typically, the upper limit of the date range is *less than one day higher* in case the dates contain times as well. The [EDATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-1586b161-4361-4a6d-939b-9d96eae962a8) will raise or lower a date by a number of months the equal to the integer in its *months* parameter.

For all intents and purposes, there is no adverse effect when using full column references with SUMIFS.